# Would anyone explain to me the use of the preposition of time ‘to’?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

Would someone explain to me the exact meaning of the following sentence:

> Tickets are available **to** the end of the month.

Does it mean the tickets are available from the beginning until the end of the month or that tickets are only available around the end of the month?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: It's poor grammar.  The word should really be **until**.

Answer (score 1):

They probably meant to say "till the end of the month", because if you're speaking fast, it sounds almost the same.  Tickets are available from now until the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

*From* and *to* work together in English.  *From X* identifies the start, and *to X* identifies the end.

> We will work from 8am to 5pm.

One meaning of *to X* is identifying motion destination/where a motion ends.  Work is moving starting from 8am and ending when 5pm occurs.

If the *from X* part is already known or understood, it can be omitted.

> We will work to 5pm. (We already are at work or know when we start).

---

Now if you use *at*:

> Tickets are available *at* the end of the month.

that will mean that tickets are available when the end of the month happens, not from now to the end of the month.